# Angular initial bundle contains too many packages

Tags: angular, webpack

In my Angular app I have two packages for working with PDFs. One is for PDF creation "jsPDF" and one for viewing PDFs withing the app "ng2-pdf-viewer" which internally uses "pdfjs-dist".

The problem is that we have all those packages used in lazy loaded modules only, however they still appear in the initial bundle.

Can anyone suggest toolings to find out *why* those got included? Or maybe any ideas.

I've already gone through the imports and don't see any leads to the core app.

I already tried using Madge, but it either doesn't work well with Angular and all those fancy imports, or I used it in the wrong way.

Comment: Can you share your core module and lazy loaded module that contains the PDF dependencies? Also, double check that the `angular.json` isn't importing either of those dependencies.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share them. angular.json doesn't contain any scripts. All is incapsulated in components/their local services

Answer (score 0):

Well. I figured that out. It appears that one component was declared in a module that declared a few more components. One of those was used in the core app and apparently it took the whole module to the initial bundle with it.